# Set Operation Implication Proof

Tags: proof-writing, set-theory

If A\B is a subset of C, then A\C is a subset of B. I'm super confused and not sure how to do this. I attempted proof by contradiction but not understanding what to do.

Sorry, this is a duplicate I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in A\setminus C$. Then $x$ is in $A$ but not in $C$. If $x$ wasn't in $B$ then it would be in $A\setminus B\subset C$. Hence $x$ is in $B$ which proves the result.